# What are the Halachot and Minhagim of the "Young [noun] Minyan"?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I have noticed, of late, that more and more shuls are holding services that cater to a tradition I'd never heard of before. They're each called a "Young [noun] Minyan," where [noun] varies, but could be:

- [Pr](http://www.bethjacob.org/young-professionals.html)o[fe](http://presentense.org/ventures/cleveland-young-professionals-minyan)s[si](http://www.feelthelight.org/calendar.html)o[n](http://www.ozny.org/whao?post_id=84284)a[ls](http://wp.yise.org/parashas-tetzaveh-february-19-20-2016/)
- [Lead](https://www.facebook.com/GRS-Young-Leadership-Minyan-1707723299462323/)er[ship](http://www.jewishcenter.org/tefillah.html)
- P[et](http://is.gd/fPQQvO)s
- C[ou](http://www.jewishcenter.org/tefillah.html)p[le](http://www.youngcouplesminyan.com/)s
- [Robo](http://rwhitesf.blogspot.com/2012/08/shul-review-library-minyan-los-angeles.html)ni[m](http://www.cartoonjazz.com/39-Robot-Minyan.htm)
- [People](https://www.ckj.org/event/young-peoples-minyan.html)

I'm very curious about the *halachot* and *minhagim* associated with this tradition.

- How young must one be to be counted for the minyan?
- Are there other restrictions on who can be counted? Do they vary by what [noun] is?
- How does the Young X Minyan siddur differ from those of other traditions? Is it closer to Ashkenaz, Mizrach, Nesach "Sefard," or Ari?
- What other unique halachot and minhagim does this tradition follow?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Don't forget Young Israel.

Comment: @Daniel, sounds  like that could be basis for a history-oriebted answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've misheard. Allow me to clarify:

- Jung Professionals Minyan — open only to Jungian mental-health professionals. They use *nusach Schweiz*.
- Hung Leadership Minyan — open only to hanged leaders. They don't use any *nusach*, since, um, they can't speak. (It's a good thing they can't speak, as they tend to use incorrect past participles.)
- Yum Pets Minyan — open only to livestock raised for slaughter. See preceding re *nusach*.
- Yon Couples Minyan — open only to those people over there. They're too far for me to hear what *nusach* they're using.
- Lung Robonim Minyan — open only to people who check animals after slaughter. They use an [hasidic](/q/15205) *nusach*, or *nusach [Bes Yosef](/q/43974)*.
- Rung People Minyan — open only to the upwardly mobile. In the U.S., they use the [transatlantic](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-Atlantic_accent) *nusach*; in the U.K., *nusach [m'kubal](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation)*.